# How to overlap shapes using turtle: pentagon and star?

Tags: python, shapes, python-turtle

I am trying to overlap the two shapes I have below. Any advice?

import turtle

turtleStar = turtle.Turtle()

for s in range(5):

```
turtleStar.forward(100)
turtleStar.right(144)
```

for p in range(5):

```
turtleStar.forward(85)
turtleStar.right(72)
```

Comment: what do you mean by overlap?

Comment: @alexpdev I need the perimeter of the pentagon to go around the star

Comment: @alexpdev Thanks that is really close. Im trying to get that be exactly around the perimeter of the star? Like have each point of the star match each point of the pentagon. Any advice?

Comment: that is what @compositions answer does... did you try that solution?

Comment: @alexpdev yes that actually worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import turtle

turtleStar = turtle.Turtle()

for s in range(5):
    turtleStar.forward(100)
    turtleStar.right(144)

turtleStar.left(36)
turtleStar.forward(62)

for p in range(4):
    turtleStar.right(72)
    turtleStar.forward(62)
```